# Rendering taking an eternity

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Are 24 hours that I'm not sleeping, trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong or I'm just stupid and poor.

I have this laptop: Asus ROG Strix Scar 15 G532LWS

Intel I7 10875H 2.30 16M Cache, up to 5.1 GHz, 8 cores Nvidia 2070 SUPER 8GB 16GB DDR4 SO-DIMM 3200MHz 3.0 Nvme M.2 SSD

I attach a screenshot to see what I'm trying to render.

I placed the resolution at 1280x720 50 samples Noise threshold 0.1/0.01/0.001 (no difference)

And I'm rendering a frame per 15mins

My total animation is 102 frames, so this means 25 hours for a video of 4 seconds in 720P. The animation is just the car driving straight and 3 buildings.enter image description here

[image]
[image]

It is possible that my laptop is not powerful enough to render?

I use Nvidia Studio Drivers.

What else I noticed is that the rendering in the viewport is faster

I really hope someone can give me some advice, otherwise, I think I have to renounce my passion because I can't afford a better computer.

Comment: That's perfectly normal. Welcome to computer graphics. 25 hours is still very much possible on a laptop. That's good news for you. :D

Comment: Is rendering in the viewport faster? Your first screenshot shows, you've set the viewport's _Max Samples_ to 1024, in the second screenshot it says 6/1024 so it is not yet finished... Unfortunately you've cut out the part where we see the _Max Samples_ for render. If you left it at the default 4096, well that takes a hell lot of time. But since you have _Denoise_ enabled I would go much much lower. One thing I can see is, you have _Motion Blur_ enabled. Although this might look nice, it can slow down rendering _a lot_ and the viewport does not show it which makes it quicker as well.

Comment: 1280x720 50 samples on a 2070 shouldn't take that long. More like 2mn. Is GPU render enabled? A version of your file could help.

Comment: Now that @JagJB mentions the GPU, I realized it is greyed out so you are most likely just rendering on the CPU which is much slower. And while I write my comment I see someone has already posted it as an answer ;) So check your GPU driver and settings in the preferences and try again (still, reducing the samples can quicken up your render of course and motion blur is also still slowing it down).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct way to ask a question here. However, it seems like your GPU drivers weren't loaded correctly. This is something that I've noticed with Optix cards that happens every now and then. I can't reproduce it.

You will see that the "device" option says "GPU compute" for you except it's grayed out.

[image]

If working correctly it will look like this.

[image]

This will happen if you save a file with GPU compute and re-open it. Except the drivers aren't loaded for some reason. This is a quick fix.

Go to

Edit -> Preferences -> System and switch from Optix to something else then back to Optix.

[image]

Your GPU compute shouldn't be grayed out anymore. Try rendering again.

Comment: This reminds me of when one of the 3.x versions came out (I don't know which one), but before GPU rendering worked perfectly on my PC, but on that newer version I always had to enable it at the first start of Blender. Or to be more precise, it was greyed out like here, but going in the preferences showed it was enabled. I toggled it off and on again and it worked for the time I had Blender opened, even when opening a new project. But it was back to normal with the next Blender version shortly afterwards so I didn't bother.